# Soap raw request test tool

Tags: url, testing, soap, request

I'm looking for a simple test tool that can send a raw soap request that I can input to the URL that I input. I've found several tools (like SOAPUI) that use the WSDL and offer special testing etc, but I don't need that (or at least I would need some tutorial on how to use one of those tools for what I need). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Pick a simple tool that can submit http/s requests and allow you to add http headers
2. Make sure it submits the required HTTP headers by SOAP (like soapAction etc)
3. make sure you enclose the payload in a SOAP envelope